# Error Creating Control on Site.Master on new Web Application

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-applications

I"m experimenting with a ASP.Net4 Web Application and am having a problem with the site master page.

I create the new web application and then when I look at the site.master page in design mode (or home or about pages), I get the following display - [image]

I seem to be missing something but I cannot see what is wrong.  This is my first time trying to do a web app, normally I do web project type sites.

Comment: What happens at runtime? Does it give you a more detailed exception? It would be my guess it's a web.config issue either with a missing assembly reference or improperly registered control.

Comment: Runtime is fine.  It's odd that I should be having this problem at design time though with a brand new project